# How to write cplex output to a text file

Tags: c#, optimization, cplex, ilog

I am using the IBM cplex optimizer to solve a MIP model. What I want is cplex to log not to console, but to a .txt file. I found a method that mentions this here:
http://yalma.fime.uanl.mx/cplex11-manual/refdotnetcplex/html/ILOG.CPLEX.Cplex.SetOut.html

```
Cplex.SetOut(TextWriter s)
```

But when I call the method like this, the text file remains empty:

```
public Cplex Model= new Cplex();    
TextWriter TWoutput = File.CreateText("RunOutput.txt"));
//Add variables, constraints and solve the model
Model.SetOut(TWoutput);
```

I can't find how am i supposed to use this method. I am new to c# and cplex so please explain as simple as you can :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick check, but you are calling `SetOut()` *before* you build and solve the model aren't you? If you are calling it after you have run `Cplex` (as might be inferred from the comment) then it wouldn´t be surprising that the file would be empty.

Comment: i can't believe i missed that! thanks a lot. I called before solving the model and it works.